# jQuery outputting NaN

Tags: jquery, nan

For some reason the code is outputting **NaN** on the website, but its working on the fiddle.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var arrTotals = [];
var totalAmount = 0;

$( ".cartprice" ).each(function( index ) {

    arrTotals[index] = $(this).text(); 
    console.log(arrTotals[index]);
    totalAmount+=parseFloat($(this).text());
});

console.log('Total Amount: ' + totalAmount)   
var newTotalAmount = totalAmount.toFixed(2);   

$('#thetotal').text(newTotalAmount);

});
```

Here is the Fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/4Be6N/11/**

unfortunately the page is in a backend on the CMS so I cant show you the link. There are no errors coming up in the console. Just this:

```
150.25 
25.36 
360.80 
1265.20 
26.50 
35.00 
1820.20     
£0.00 
Total Amount: NaN
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I know, this is the problem. The fiddle works but it doesnt on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: There is `£`0.00  in the last number, i think that is the problem

Comment: @Lix " but its working on the fiddle"..

Comment: @Lix seems like u haven't read the question carefully

Comment: The problem is with `£0.00`. Check this fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/4Be6N/12/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Be6N/13/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `parseFloat` on `£0.00` which is not a number so it returns `NaN`, when you add `NaN` to anything, the result is `NaN`.

Either disallow `£` signs or strip them with a Regular Expression:

```
"£0.00".replace(/[^0-9.]/g,"") // strip anything that is not a number or a dot
```

Comment: The unit should be outside the input anyway, because the code probably expects value to be in a specific unit.

Comment: i'm confused. The £ is not in the jquery nor in the output for the total. The total is put inside the #thetotal span and is only thing in there

Comment: Ah, I seem, the output on the page has a £ in it. I'll regex that out. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one of the texts isn't a number:   NaN = Not a number

From your console logs it is easy to see the problem:

`isNaN( parseFloat("£0.00") ) == true`

Comment: Actually, nothing is equal to NaN, `NaN == NaN` is false.

Comment: oops, thats right,  I wanted to highlight the problematic part, will fix